# How to mimic constructor in JavaScript in OOP style?

Tags: javascript, oop

In an OOP way, I am defining a Person "class" as follows:

```
var Person = {
  name: '',
  age: 32,
  gender: 'male',
  interests: ['music', 'skiing'],
  bio: function() {
    alert(this.name[0] + ' ' + this.name[1] + ' is ' + this.age + ' years old. He likes ' + this.interests[0] + ' and ' + this.interests[1] + '.');
  },
  greeting: function() {
    alert('Hi! I\'m ' + this.name + '.');
  }
};
```

Now, I am instantiating the above class.

```
var person1= Object.create(Person);
person1.name = 'personname';
person1.greeting();
```

How can I mimic a constructor so that when Object.create(Person) creates a new object, the constructor code is automatically computed?

Comment: You can’t. Why not use… a constructor?

Comment: Also, `Person` is an **Object** and not a *Class*

Comment: Could be a typo, but `animal ` is not defined in your example.

Comment: what are you trying to do? why do you need to mimic sth. that already exists? why don't you just use the existing mechanics, but instead you work around them and ask how to mimic them? What's the purpose of this, what are your intentions/reasons/thoughts?

Comment: @Thomas Avoiding the keywords `new`, `this`, and constructor functions is a common style in JavaScript that comes from Douglas Crockford. He's written some popular books, and works on the board for ECMAScript, so I can see how they would like to do things this way.

Comment: If 4castle is right about this being Crockford advice: ignore it, use a constructor.

Comment: @Ryan It's on page 30 of [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://bdcampbell.net/javascript/book/javascript_the_good_parts.pdf).

Comment: sorry for my mis wording. I couldn't find constructor syntax so was looking for a way to mimic constructor. sorry i am an amateur at javascript. i am curious why new should be avoided?

Comment: @user734861 The reasoning is that it would be dangerous if you accidentally called the constructor function without the `new` prefix, and that there are safer ways of accomplishing the same thing. There's more info in the book (I recommend it). It's mostly a style choice, so you can make your own judgement.

Comment: so i am in dilemma. which one is better the one suggested by Alexander Elgin or the one you (4castle) suggested.

Comment: @user734861 You will have to define "better". My answer would use less memory since it utilizes the `prototype` for properties that are common among instances, but it's mostly a style decision. The answer from Nina is more comparable in memory usage.

Comment: thanks for the book. looks like this is a great book for someone jumping into javascript.

Comment: thanks for the book. looks like this is a great book for someone jumping into javascript.

Comment: @4castle: Sorry, I know it’s Crockford advice; I was wondering if the OP was avoiding it *because* of Crockford advice.

Comment: @user734861: Out of the answers to this question, I strongly recommend you use Nina’s (although the IIFE isn’t necessary; you can just define a function as normal and add things to its prototype). Make sure you have [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would wrap up the code in a function, and call it there. [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) will establish a relationship with the `prototype`, but won't call any additional code automatically.

```
function person(name) {
  var person1 = Object.create(Person);
  person1.name = name;
  return person1;
}

person('personname').greeting();
```

You should also avoid uppercasing the first letter of variables unless they are functions which should be called using `new`. This is a naming convention used only for constructor functions.

Answer (score 1):

You could make an real class for use with `new`.

```js
var Person = function () {
    var Person = function () {
        this.name = ['', ''];
        this.age = 32;
        this.gender = 'male';
        this.interests = ['music', 'skiing'];
    };
  
    Person.prototype.bio = function() {
        return this.name[0] + ' ' + this.name[1] + ' is ' + this.age + ' years old. He likes ' + this.interests[0] + ' and ' + this.interests[1] + '.';
    };
    Person.prototype.greeting = function() {
        return 'Hi! I\'m ' + this.name + '.';
    };
    return Person;
}();


var p1 = new Person;

p1.name = ['Tom', 'Sawyer'];
console.log(p1.bio());
console.log(p1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Person = function(name) {
  this.name = name || '';
  this.age = 32;
  this.gender = 'male';
  this.interests = ['music', 'skiing'];
  
  this.bio = function() {
    alert(this.name[0] + ' ' + this.name[1] + ' is ' + this.age + ' years old. He likes ' + this.interests[0] + ' and ' + this.interests[1] + '.');
  };
  
  this.greeting = function() {
    alert('Hi! I\'m ' + this.name + '.');
  };
};

var person1= new Person('personname');
person1.greeting();
```

Comment: so all the assignments for example this.name, this.age, this.gender, this.interests are equivalent to constructor code. is that right?

Comment: @user734861 Correct. That's the way how constructor is defined in JS. ES6 has a more elegant OOP syntax.

Comment: @user734861 this is a constructor

Comment: My interpretation of the question was they wanted to "simulate" a constructor. Meaning `new` was off-limits.

Comment: This doesn’t mimic a constructor; this *is* a constructor, and it doesn’t make use of its prototype like the original code with `Object.create` would.